# Error en el tiempo de ejecución de una macro

Tags: macros, depuración

Cuando ejecuto una macro hay ocasiones que me sale un error, en otras ocasiones va bien.
Este es el error que me da.
"-2147417848 (80010108) en tiempo de ejecución.
Cuando le doy a depurar me sale lo siguiente:

```
Sub Grabarcierreobra()
'
' Grabarcierreobra Macro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    Columns("D:L").Select
    Range("D2").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historial cierres obra").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
Sub Grabarcierredeobra()
'
' Grabarcierredeobra Macro
'

'
    Columns("D:L").Select
    Range("D2").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Historial cierres obra").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight  (esta línea me sale resaltada en amarillo)
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Ocurre cada vez con más frecuencia, ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?